# Cakephp select query without model name

Tags: cakephp

```
$this->User->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', '"0" as age'));

this function generates the following query

SELECT `User`.`id`, `User."0" as age` FROM `db`.`t_users` AS `User` WHERE 1 = 1
```

I don't want the `db`.`t_users` to act as 'User', rather make it a raw query cause `User."0" as age` is not a valid selection. The query may be like:

```
SELECT `id`, `"0" as age` FROM `db`.`t_users` WHERE 1 = 1
```

Without using custom query, how can I generate the query without `User`?

I'm using cakephp 2.3.4

Comment: It looks like this code is trying to select a column name that is named 0 is that correct? that would be why it's not working. CakePHP aliases the result as User so you can use it within its conventions. So $test = $this->User->find() would let you access the results as $test['User']['column']. So unless there is a reason you don't want to alias it for that, you need to investigate why you're using a column named 0. If you do have a column named 0 either change it, or wrap it in ` so '`0` as age' might work

Comment: Sorry, I didn't figure it out in my question. 0 is not name of any column, I want to select the users with initial age value 0, the table doesn't have any column name `age` also. It works fine in raw query, but facing problem in cake

Comment: Use **[virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html)**

Answer (score 1):

You could define age as a virtual field on the User model:-

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $virtualFields = array(
        'age' => '0'
    );

}
```

Then your query would be:-

```
$this->User->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'age')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead  of using  `"0" as age'`  use a virtual field. That should work.